# Cloudflare cashing everyhing

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare on server containing CRM but I'm facing problem that CloudFlare is cashing the whole page so when I add new data to page the new updates don't appear until I press CTRL+F5 and when I press F5 it's return the old page before the update.
I think CloudFlare is caching everything. What I Should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purge cache in Cloudflare.

This is an example.
First:
[image: example1]
Then:[image: example2]

Edit:
You can create a page rule for not caching the specific page at all.
Example: (This will let browser cache 30 min.)
[image: example3]

Comment: thank you for your answer but my problem is after purging the cash again its caching everything for example I have this page www.mywebsite.com/customer/13
after editing this customer information its still showing the old page with the old data

Answer (score 1):

In cloudflare page rule settings, bypass all URLs and write another rule to cache only static contents like css,js,images, etc.. and place this rule on top order.

Also check your cache-control settings on response header. Your problem seems like cache control header settings.